# Angular form status validator

Tags: angular, validation, angular-directive, angular2-directives

I'm trying to write custom form validator. I have this test component, where are three checkboxes.
Main form should be valid only if at least one checkbox is checked.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-69q3rq

There are two components - main-form, and inside is options component (this is just for testing purposes)

I set form validator (in main-form component) like this:
`appFormStatusValidator [isInvalid]="isInvalid">`

and handle value of isInvalid property when any checkbox value is changed.

But inside of validation, the isValid property is false, even if property on the form is true (and vice versa).

Could you please tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot.

I expect, that button will be enabled only if at least one checkbox is checked, and button will be disabled when all three checkboxes are unchecked.

Comment: please update the question with the relevant code also, since if stackblitz link goes away, the question will become useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed a lot of code, like the event binding and all the `invalid` flags, I just provided an input to the directive called `toValidateFieldNames` which contains the checkbox form field names to validate, and when we do the validation, we use the array operation `some` which checks if any of the provided elements in the array are true, then it returns true, which I inverted using `!` to achieve the functionality you wanted, also when you use `ControlContainer` then is no need for extra form validations, the checkboxes in the child component are automatically detected by the parent!

Since we are updating the form values, the validator get called on value changes, so there is no need for the events like `change` on the checkboxes!

Below is a working example for your reference!

directive

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {
  NG_VALIDATORS,
  AbstractControl,
  ValidationErrors,
  FormGroup,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appFormStatusValidator]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: FormStatusValidatorDirective,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class FormStatusValidatorDirective {
  @Input() toValidateFieldNames: Array<string> = [];

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    const formGroup = control as FormGroup;
    console.log(formGroup);
    // Your custom validation logic
    if (formGroup && !this.toValidateFieldNames?.some((field: string) => formGroup.value[field])) {
      return { formStatusInvalid: true }; // Form status is invalid
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

options.com.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer, FormGroup, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { DataInterface } from '../data.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-options',
  templateUrl: './options.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./options.component.css'],
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm }],
})
export class OptionsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() item: DataInterface | null = null;
  formGroup!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private controlContainer: ControlContainer) {
    this.formGroup = this.controlContainer.control as FormGroup;
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

options.com.html

```
<div>
  <span>is invalid (inside option component): {{ formGroup.valid }}</span>
</div>
<br />
<ng-container *ngIf="item">
  <div>
    <mat-checkbox name="option1" [(ngModel)]="item.option1"
      >Option1</mat-checkbox
    >
  </div>
  <br />
  <div>
    <mat-checkbox name="option2" [(ngModel)]="item.option2"
      >Option2</mat-checkbox
    >
  </div>
  <br />
  <div>
    <mat-checkbox name="option3" [(ngModel)]="item.option3"
      >Option3</mat-checkbox
    >
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

main form.com.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { DataInterface } from '../data.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-form',
  templateUrl: './main-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-form.component.css'],
})
export class MainFormComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  @ViewChild('inputForm') inputForm?: NgForm;

  item: DataInterface = { id: 1, name: 'test' };

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

main form.com.html

```
<div>
  {{ item | json }}
</div>


<form #inputForm="ngForm"
appFormStatusValidator [toValidateFieldNames]="[
'option1',
'option2',
'option3',
]">
  <hr/>

  <app-options [item]="item"/>

  <hr/>
  <div>
    <span>is invalid (main component): {{ inputForm.form.invalid }}</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>form status: {{ inputForm.form.status}}</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>form errors: {{ inputForm.form.errors | json}}</span>
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <button [disabled]="inputForm.form.invalid">
    Submit
  </button>

</form>
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-pnesp5?file=src%2Ftest%2Fmain-form%2Fmain-form.component.css,src%2Ftest%2Fmain-form%2Fmain-form.component.html,src%2Ftest%2Foptions%2Foptions.component.ts,src%2Ftest%2Fmain-form%2Fmain-form.component.ts)

Comment: @kkthlv Could you raise a new question, because the question and the answer will go out of sync! The stackblitz provided looks different from what was given in the question!

Comment: I think it is still the same question - if I change isInvalid property on the main-form, why the property inside validator do not reflect that?

Comment: @kkthlv I'm sorry, but my answer does not even bother with `isInvalid` plz check my answer where it works! There is no need for this extra code! I understand my answer might not work for the new scenario, but I will be glad to look at it on a new question! Hope you understand!

Comment: I understand, thanks for your time, I really appreciate that. New question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77980557/angular-form-status-validator-2

Comment: @kkthlv Thank you very much, I updated my answer in the new question